# Depth & Buffer in OpenGL and OpenCV

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm making a program in C++ with OpenGL and OpenCV, in which it will render a 3D object in a camera feed from OpenCV. It works well if I only render an object, but I can't give lighting to my object because everytime I enable `GLUT_DEPTH_TEST` or anything related to depth, the 3D object doesn't appear in the window. But if the depth test is disabled then the object appears flat. I also have added `GLUT_DEPTH` in `glutInitDisplayMode` and `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` in `glClear`.

I think the problem is because I also use stencil functions in my program. I put `GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT` in `glClear` too but if I remove that the program doesn't work. Anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Try adding `glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS,0,~0x0);` before your draw command.

Comment: @dari still doesn't work :/ is there any code I have to add before that function?